# Div inside scroll area being scrolled away

Tags: html, css

I have a Scrollable area and buttons `<` `>` to make it scroll.
I need to have those button's `span` inside the main div (`spinAreaDiv`) without they getting scrolled away.

**Q:** What am I missing? ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/53AMT/))
I tried having the `span` with `float`, then they are inside `spinAreaDiv`but get scrolled away...

HTML

```
<div id="spinAreaDiv"> 
<span id="leftclick" class="left">&nbsp; < &nbsp;</span>
<span id="rightclick" class="right">&nbsp; > &nbsp;</span>
<div class="spin-bullets">
    zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...
    zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz... 
    zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...
    zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...
    zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...zzzZZzzz...
</div>
```

JS:

```
spinAreaDiv = document.getElementById('spinAreaDiv');
scrollEff = new Fx.Scroll(spinAreaDiv, {
wait: false,
duration: 1000,
offset: {
    'x': 0,
        'y': 0
},
transition: Fx.Transitions.Quad.easeInOut
});

thumbLeft = document.getElementById('leftclick');
thumbRight = document.getElementById('rightclick');

thumbLeft.addEvent("click", function () {
scrollEff.start((spinAreaDiv.getScroll().x) - 400, 0);
});
thumbRight.addEvent("click", function () {
scrollEff.start((spinAreaDiv.getScroll().x) + 400, 0);
});
```

CSS:

```
#spinAreaDiv {
width:500px;
margin-left:10%;
overflow:auto;
height:60px;
background-color:grey;
}
span {
margin-top:20px;
background-color:red;
z-index:100;
}
span.right {position:absolute;right:0px;}
span.left {position:absolute;left: 0;}
.spin-bullets {
width:10000px;
height:35px;
padding-top:10px;
top:0px;
background-color:#066;
}
```

(Using Mootools Fx.Scroll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your span buttons  should be standing outside of #spinAreaDiv or take reference of position from a parent that do not scroll.
http://jsfiddle.net/53AMT/1/.
if you wrap your slider in :anther div;

```
#myslider {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    width:500px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

They can lay over it though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with "MooTools", but you could change the left/right offset on the buttons during scroll:

```
spinAreaDiv.addEvent('scroll', function(ev){
  thumbLeft.style.left = spinAreaDiv.getScroll().x + 'px';    
  thumbRight.style.right = (-spinAreaDiv.getScroll().x) + 'px';
});
```

([test](http://jsfiddle.net/B8SRy/))

Also, you need to position your spinArea:

```
#spinAreaDiv {
  position: relative;
}
```

It might be a better idea to move your scroll content into another DIV with the scroll width and height, and put the buttons there. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rRjUH/).

Comment: Thank you for helping with this! ( +1 because I cannot accept two answers)